# Why does `nuxt generate` with @nuxt/pwa module generates always default icon in Gitlab-CI?

Tags: gitlab, icons, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci, progressive-web-apps

I have the following problem. I am using nuxt with the pwa module to generate a pre-rendered webpage. The @nuxt/pwa icon module should generate the different sized icons for the manifest.

This is also working when I run `nuxt generate` on my laptop.

In my gitlab-ci pipeline the generation also is working but it is always generating the default nuxt icon

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/6ff34ec8760318b99888ee4b75d1e265170a84b9/6479c/logos/nuxt.svg]

This icon I can not in my workspace so I guess it is somehow referenced in the docker build from node_modules.

I am using the following gitlab-ci job

```
build:
  image: node:alpine
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*
    expire_in: 14 days
  only:
    - master
```

The `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-beta.20",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
  }
```

I also tried a lot of different settings in my nuxt.conf.js as I guessed that the icon is not referenced correctly.

This was my last try

```
  pwa: {
    icon: {
      source: resolve(__dirname, './client/static/icon.png'),
    },
  },
```

But as it is found locally I thik that it is right.

Has anyone an idea why the `nuxt generate` does not work in gitlab-ci?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue seems to be the old cache located at `/node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon`

Nuxt doesn't generate new icons if the filenames are not changed so that is why the default icons are used. Especially if your new icon file is 'icon.png'.

You could go about this three ways:

1. Delete the cache at `/node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon` before deploying but this only works with local/dev environment so this is out.
2. You could rename your file as the other comment suggested but you would have to rename it every time you change the file. So while this would work, it is still far from good, even for a hacky solution.
3. The third approach would be to delete that folder in your yarn/npm generate script. This would look something like this:

```
generate: 'rm -r /node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon && nuxt generate';
```

Comment: For me i have to use `generate: 'rm -r node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon && nuxt generate';
` (remove `/` before node_modules).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and the icons didn't get updated also on my local environment. For now I was able to fix it by adding

```
pwa: {
    icon: {
         fileName: 'app-icon.png',
    },
},
```

to my nuxt.config.js and change the filename accordingly. But thats probably a little hacky.

I use Netlify for deployment and cleared the cache there but with no luck. Did you cleared your Runner Cache in Gitlab and then tried again?

Comment: I am not sure and I have to narrow down if it was the clearing of the cache or the change of the config with explicit referencing the icon but now it works. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I double-checked my pipeline. It was the runners cache. After clearing it, I can also use the non-explicit version of `nuxt.config.js`. Failed with one of the two hard things in computer science (naming things and) cache invalidation :-O

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me,

Delete the following:

1. node_modules/.cache
2. .nuxt
3. dist(if generated)

Then do the following:

```
npm install
npm run generate
```